# Can we auto-tag scheduled builds?

Tags: teamcity

We are setting up an scheduled nightly build that we'd like to be able to tag as such when it runs. Is this possible with TeamCity 10?

The reason for this is that if we don't tag it, it's tricky to find in in the build list, since the only way to identify it is by looking at the run time.

For now we ended up cloning our configuration and only have it run every night. But I don't like this since it duplicates the configuration which means we have to maintain 2 sets of build steps, agent requirements, etc etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

1. Use a [build template](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Configuration+Template), which makes it easy to maintain two build configurations with slightly different requirements. I would recommend this as the most straightforward solution with very little overhead.
2. You can tag builds conditionally through the [REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildTags). Write a script that checks the %teamcity.build.triggeredBy% parameter. If it's a scheduled build, add a tag using the REST API.

I would think these are the simplest way to achieve what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give both of this a try.